# ¿Cuya presencia fue mandada en esta frase?

Tags: gramática, objetos-indirectos, significado-en-contexto, sujeto

Lo apuntado por debajo de este currículum del año de 1820 dice:

*El Supremo Concejo de Estado ha mandado se le tenga presente en virtud de Real Orden de 1 de Agosto comunicado por el Ministerio de Marina*

Mi duda tiene que ver con la indirección del "le". **¿Cuya presencia fue mandada?** Supongo que será:

- o la del documento,
- o la del sujeto Fernández,
- o la de su solicitud del puesto,
- o quizás una ambigüedad.

[image: Extracto de los méritos y servicios...]

Comment: Por favor lo que me he reído leyendo el currículum. El párrafo de la insurrección es insuperable!

Comment: Yo entiendo que, al tenerse presente el documento que detalla los antecedentes de la persona, también se tiene presente a la persona que goza de esos antecedentes (por ejemplo, para una eventual designación).

Comment: MIra las definiciones de mandar en la RAE: https://dle.rae.es/mandar?m=form 6. tr. Manifestar la voluntad de que se haga algo. Por ejemplo.

Comment: La otra definición relevante será “tener alguien presente”: Conservar en la memoria y tomar en consideración algo para usarlo cuando convenga, o a alguien para atenderle en ocasión oportuna. https://dle.rae.es/tener

Answer (score -1):

"*El Supremo Concejo de Estado ha mandado se le tenga presente en virtud de Real Orden de 1 de Agosto comunicado por el Ministerio de Marina*"

Al leer este párrafo más detenidamente entiendo que, "El Supremo Consejo de Estado" ha mandado que Don José Agustín, que acaba de llegar a la península con tres niños encargado de su educación en un colegio, y que previamente había sido también capellán de la Armada, se le tenga  **en cuenta**, en base a la normativa del Real Orden del 1 de Agosto, imagino que para ocupar un cargo o vacante similar a la que ocupaba en la Armada, y se le haga comunicado al Ministerio de Marina.

Comment: Interesante, pues como aún no veo ningún rasgo de un delito ni un arrepentimiento, por favor aclare cómo o dónde ha percibido ese significado.

Comment: @Aaron Brick, te pido disculpas, he leído con más detenimiento el texto y estaba equivocado, por un momento me fui por otra parte. Aquí se hace referencia a su trayectoria y vicisitudes en general para al final, decir que El Supremo Consejo de Estado manda que se te tenga en cuenta, conforme a una Real Orden, imagino que para alguna vacante o incorporación en un puesto similar en la Armada. Gracias y te pido disculpas nuevamente.